# css: style image grid

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<div><p>Recollida</p></div>
  <div ng-repeat="image in images">
    <a ng-href="{{image.path}}" class="imageAnchor">
      <figure>
        <img ng-src="{{image.path}}" alt="">
      </figure>
    </a>
</div>
```

Now I want to display the images in rows of 4, and I want every row to have the same height.
I've been struggling with this for a while and I want to know if there is any way to achieve this or if it's better to look for another solution. The `<div>` in the code above is originaly inside a larger `<div>` with a determined height.

Comment: Read through the question twice. Struggling to understand what you need. 4 images in a row that's all the same size?

Comment: Personally, I read it as  2 x 2 Grid. If all in a line, use Flex, otherwise Grid is the tool to use for more complicated layout.

Comment: fixed the text a little, I hope it's more understandable now.

Comment: Much clearer, I have gone and deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using flex

```
<div class="imagesContainer">
   <div ng-repeat="image in images" class="imageContainer">
       <a ng-href="{{image.path}}" class="imageAnchor">
          <figure>
             <img ng-src="{{image.path}}" alt="">
          </figure>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>


.imagesContainer{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
}
.imageContainer{
 width:25%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lsp2f5hk/

Read more about flex here : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: It works just fine. Just one more thing, I realized I also need to make the images all the same size, how could I also fix that? Thanks!!!

Comment: Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/1uf4uyg1/   I have set img width to 90% of imageContainer and 5% padding on both sides . You can  adjust padding and width according to your use case. Also I have removed figure tag and made anchor tag display block, So that whole image is clickable.